# What options does Terminal pass to bash on startup?

Tags: terminal, macos, bash, macports, command-line

In the Terminal preferences, I'm able to configure the Terminal to "Open shells with:" -> "Command (complete path):" `/opt/local/bin/bash`.

What options is the terminal passing when invoking this command?  Terminal appears to run each shell as a login shell, so I'm assuming `--login` is being passed?

Is there any Apple documentation that gives an overview of exactly what is being run when you open a terminal window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No arguments are passed. The terminal runs `login -pfq $USER $PROGRAM`, which in turn runs the specified program. `login` signals to the program that it is a login shell by prepending a `-` to `argv[0]` (the program name).

For the default shell, Terminal actually does something different. It invokes `login -pfl $USER /bin/bash -c exec -la bash /bin/bash`, where the `-l` option to login tells it *not* to run the command as login shell, while the `-l` option to `exec` tells it to run its argument as a login shell (by adding the dash). The reason while this is done is that `login` also sets the current directory to the user's home directory when it runs a program as a login shell, while `exec` doesn't. This allows the Terminal to open shells in the same current directory as the current tab, without `login` setting it back to the home directory.

Comment: When I change the terminal preferences to `/opt/local/bin/bash`, how does `login -pfq $USER $PROGRAM` change?  Just so I understand your first paragraph, do you mean Terminal runs `login -pfq cwilson /opt/local/bin/-bash`?

Comment: No, the terminal runs `login -pfq cwilson /opt/local/bin/bash`. Then login executes bash, but passes `-bash` in `argv[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

The command:

```
/opt/local/bin/bash
```

essentially instructs Terminal.app to load an interactive bash shell (the path for your example is likely the macports version). Initially when you open Terminal it starts a login shell session (in bash). Login shells can read files such as `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` that setup environment variables for your session, so what is being run is mostly indicative of what is configured within those files.

In general, by default when opening a bash shell from Terminal these things would be run:

Processes

```
bash
login
```

Open Files and Ports

```
/bin/bash
/usr/lib/dyld
/private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64
/dev/ttys000
```

More Information:

> [Official Bash Website](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/bash.html)
>
> [Apple Man Page: bash(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html)