# Why is ~/.zprofile always sourced on every interactive session?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh

from zsh document, `~/.zprofile` should only be sourced at login shell, and should NOT be sourced at every interactive session (for example, a new tab in a terminal).

- I am running MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3 (20D91).

But I can confirm that my `~/.zprofile` is sourced at every interactive session (a new tab). Why is that? Is this a bug? How to stop this incorrect behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each Terminal tab is a login session on macOS by default. You can run `w` to see that each tab/tty running a shell has a process name starting with `-` attached to it (which indicates a login shell).

Additional information (related to `bash`, but the same is applicable to other shells)

- [What options does Terminal pass to bash on startup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114830/what-options-does-terminal-pass-to-bash-on-startup/114840#114840)
- [Why doesn't .bashrc run automatically?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/why-doesnt-bashrc-run-automatically) (some of the answers explain details)
- [What are the differences between /usr/bin/login and /usr/bin/bash?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8341/what-are-the-differences-between-usr-bin-login-and-usr-bin-bash)
- [Why doesn't Mac OS X source ~/.bashrc?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119711/why-doesnt-mac-os-x-source-bashrc/119714#119714)

PS: If I remember correctly we have a Q&A which goes into even more detail on this including a rationale *why* macOS considers each Terminal window/tab to be a login shell. I didn't find it yet though...

Comment: You can nicely test this if you echo something in `.zprofile`. If you then run `zsh` in a `zsh` shell, you will come to the conclusion that it will not source `.zprofile` again, but yes, new tabs and windows are login shells, not so much in Linux though. And MacOS behaves the same when you switch your shell to `/bin/bash`. New terminal windows will always source `.bash_profile` or `.profile`, but unless to `zsh` `bash` will never source `.bashrc` in login shells, so that's why `.bash_profile` typically sources `.bashrc` manually.